# Confusion between these two combinatorial problems

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

These two problems both come from Hossein Pishro-Nik's Introduction to Probability.

The first problem (which I will explain the set up and the solution):
Suppose we have 20 white phones and 10 black phones. We choose 9 phones at random. What is the probability that we have exactly four black phones.

Solution: The probability of this will be the number of ways we can have 4 black phones over the number of ways we can have any 9 phones.
$$P(\text{exactly four phones}) = \frac{\binom {10} {4} \binom {20} {5}}{\binom {30} {9}} $$
The numerator is the number of ways to select 4 black phones from 10 black phones times the number of ways to select 5 white phones from 20 white phones. The numerator is the number of combinations of 9 we can have from the 30 total phones.

What I don't understand is why selecting the 4 black phones doesn't determine the entire combination. Since the phones have to be black **or** white, if we say only four of them are black, then the rest have to be black so there's no need to multiply by $\binom {20} {5}$. This reasoning works for the next problem.

Second problem: Suppose we have a 20 by 20 grid. We start at the point $(0,0)$ and make only upward or rightward steps to get to the point $(40, 20).$

Solution: Here choosing the sequence of 10 rightward steps or choosing the sequence of 10 upward steps completely determines the path since we can only move up or right.
As a result, the answer is $ \binom {20}{10}$.

I don't see why the reasoning for the second question wouldn't work for the first question since the choice is binary (literally black or white).

Comment: The answer to the second question is $\binom{40}{20}$ since $20$ of the $40$ moves from $0$ to $20$ must be rightward.

Answer (score 2):

For the first problem, imagine that each of the phones have unique serial numbers.

So, we have for example the phones Black0001, Black0002, Black0003, ..., Black0009, Black0010, Red0001, Red0002, ..., Red0020.

Now... maybe to a normal person, they might not think to open up the phone's case and look inside at the serial number of the phone and so to them, the only things they recognize about the phone is that it is black or it is red and otherwise can't tell the phones apart... but to you and to me, we are aware of the fact that these serial numbers exist and that the phones occupy different positions in time and space to one another and are in fact distinct physical objects comprised of different atoms.

Now, the action of selecting nine phones at random we can describe the outcomes by the set of which phones we selected and under any reasonable interpretation of the problem will be such that each subset of nine phones will be equally likely to occur.  There are $\binom{30}{9}$ different such subsets.  Note here the fact that we are using $\binom{30}{9}$, the number of subsets of the set where the thirty phones are all considered distinct.  Yes... to a lay person who isn't aware of the existence of the serial numbers who treats the phones as appearing identical, we might have said there are $10$ different possible outcomes, being that we got zero black, one black, two black phones total, etc... however, one should be aware that those ten outcomes are not equally likely to occur.  It is more likely to have gotten, say, $3$ black phones and $6$ red phones than it is to have gotten $9$ black phones and we always try to use sample spaces where each outcome is equally likely to occur to help facilitate calculations.

So, among our $\binom{30}{9}$ possibilities, we include as possibilities having drawn the phones with serial numbers Black0001,Black0002,Black0003,Black0004,Red0001,Red0002,Red0003,Red0004,Red0005 and this is considered a *different* outcome than having drawn the phones Black0005,Black0006,Black0007,Black0008,Red0015,Red0016,Red0017,Red0018,Red0019 and so on...

Your claim that everything is determined once you have drawn the black phones is incorrect.  Having drawn only the two black phones Black0001,Black0002 will indeed determine the *number* of black phones and red phones drawn, but it will *not* be enough information to determine which of the red phones it was that were drawn to complete the total collection.  It is thus ambiguous whether Black0001,Black0002 continues with Red0001,Red0002,Red0003,... or if it continues with Red0001,Red0005,Red0010,... or if it continues some other way...

We count the number of valid cases by choosing *which* black phones it was *and which red phones it was*, not having stopped too early in the process of calculating.  There are $\binom{10}{4}$ ways to select which black phones they were and $\binom{20}{5}$ ways to select which red phones they were.  Multiplying gives us the number of ways of having selected four black phones.  Dividing that result by the number of ways of having selected nine phones regardless gives us the probability of having selected four black phones as being $\dfrac{\binom{10}{4}\binom{20}{5}}{\binom{30}{9}}$

It is worth pointing out as well that these calculations so far have been where the *order in which the phones were drawn does not matter*.  The reason is that it is convenient to have done so.  That is not to say that the order should not matter, or cannot matter... just that it is convenient to have treated it as though it does not matter.  You could have run the same calculations where order of selection mattered as well and have arrived at the same answer... effectively making the probability $\dfrac{\binom{10}{4}\binom{20}{5}\cdot 9!}{30\cdot 29\cdot 28\cdots 22}$ which one can see equals what we had before.

---

Now... on to the second problem of counting the number of lattice paths.  You do have a mistake there... the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(20,20)$ will have been $\binom{40}{20}$, not $\binom{20}{10}$.

That being said, here we are not choosing distinct rights from a collection of distinct rights, and choosing distinct ups from a collection of distinct ups.  All rights are identical.  There are no hidden serial numbers here to look at.

The only thing that matters here is whether the first step in the path is to the right or is up, whether the second step in the path is to the right or up, and so on...

Could you have looked at a similar related problem where we want to count lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(20,20)$ and we color each individual step in the process with a particular differently colored crayon on our paper and we treat two lattice paths as different if the shapes of the path *or the colors at each step* of the path don't match exactly?  Sure!  And that is an interesting problem to explore, but here it is safe to assume that this is not the problem being discussed.  One path is treated the same as the other path iff the shapes of the path are the same.

Now, to count this, we notice that regardless what shape the path takes, there will be $40$ steps total taken in the path.  Among these steps, exactly twenty of them will be up and the remaining twenty of them are to the right.  Now... we select *from the available collection of positions in the sequence*, which of those positions will be filled by rights and the remainder will be ups.

Again, I must emphasize, we are not picking *which rights out of the available collection of rights they are* like how we picked which black phones they were out of the available collection of black phones... here all rights are the same as all other rights.

There are $40$ available positions, and we picked $20$ of them to be rights (*note, simultaneously, since the order of selection does not matter.  we are counting subsets of positions, not sequences of positions*).  As such, there are $\binom{40}{20}$ such lattice paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose nine telephones at random, the chance that you will have four black telephones is the same as the chance that you will have five white telephones -- you can't have one without the other.

Following your argument, this probability would be

$$ P(\text{$5$ white telephones}) \stackrel?= \frac{\binom{20}{5}}{\binom{30}{9}}. $$

But this comes out to a different result than

$$ P(\text{$4$ black telephones}) \stackrel?= \frac{\binom{10}{4}}{\binom{30}{9}}. $$

So there is something wrong in this way of computing the probability.

---

Your second example is not a probability question. It's a simple counting question.

One thing that makes the path on the grid simpler is that at each step you really have only two choices: up or right. Unlike the telephones, where each black telephone was a distinct object before your choice (and remains one afterward), and where it makes sense to ask, if the first telephone you chose is black, *which black telephone was it,* if your first step on the grid is to the right, there's no question of "which rightward step" it was. It can only be the rightward step from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0).$

Also, unlike the telephones, where choosing one telephone as your first telephone does not prevent any other telephone from being chosen as the second one,
making a rightward step from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ rules out a lot of steps that otherwise might have been possible.
For example, after $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ you cannot have a rightward step from
$(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$.
You also cannot have an upward step from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$.
Yet you could have chosen an upward step from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$
and then a rightward step from $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$
if you had done those two steps first.

So the analogy "the step is either rightward or upward; the telephone is either black or white" is a bad analogy. There are all kinds of constraints on the steps that have no analogous constraints for the telephones, and freedoms of choice of telephones that do not exist for the steps on the grid.

This is why you have to actually consider the mechanics of a problem and not just grab a few numbers from it and throw them into an arbitrary formula.